# Why is this wrong!? Generating strings

Tags: string, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault

I've been trying to generate strings in this way:

a

b

.

.

z

aa

ab

.

.

zz

.

.

.

.

zzzz

And I want to know why Segmentation fault (core dumped) error is prompted when it reaches 'yz'. I know my code don't cover all the posibles strings like 'zb' or 'zc', but that's not all the point, I want to know why this error. I am not a master in coding as you see so please try to explain it clearly. Thanks :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void move_positions (char s[]);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char s[28]; 
    s[0] = ' ';
    s[1] = '\0';
    int a = 0;
    for(int r = 'a'; r <= 'z'; r++)
    {
        for(int t ='a';t <='z'; t++)
        {   
            for(int u = 'a';u <= 'z'; u++)
            {   
                for(int y = 'a'; y <= 'z'; y++)                                    
                {                                          
                    s[a] = (char)y;  
                    printf ("%s\n", s);                                                                    
                    if (s[0] == 'z')
                    {                                                                                      
                        move_positions(s);
                        a++;
                    } 
                }
                s[a-1] = (char)u;
            }
            s[a-2] = (char)t;
        }
        s[a-3] = (char)r;
    }
return 0;
}


void move_positions (char s[])
{
    char z[28];
    z[0] = ' ';
    z[1] = '\0';
    strcpy(s, strcat(z, s));
}
```

Comment: Please update the title so the question will be useful to future visitors. Otherwise it risks being closed as too localized.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's compile with debugging turned on:

```
gcc -g prog.c -o prog
```

Now let's run it under a debugger:

```
> gdb prog
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1822) (Sun Aug  5 03:00:42 UTC 2012)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin"...Reading symbols for shared libraries .. done

(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/andrew/Documents/programming/sx/13422880/prog 
Reading symbols for shared libraries +............................. done
a
b
c
d
e
...

yu
yv
yw
yx
yy
yz

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x00007fffc0bff6c5
0x0000000100000c83 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbff728) at prog.c:22
22                      s[a] = (char)y;
```

Ok, it crashed on line 22, trying to do `s[a] = (char)y`. What's `a`?

```
(gdb) p a
$1 = 1627389953
```

So you're setting the ~1.6 millionth entry of the array `s`. What is `s`?

```
(gdb) ptype s
type = char [28]
```

Saving 1.6 million entries in a 28-element array? That's not going to work. Looks like you need to reset `a` to zero at the start of some of your loops.

Comment: Thanks andrew! You're right! But I don't know why it changes from 1 to 1,6 million. I've tried to solve the problem but suddendly it changes without getting in to the statement in which "a" changes its value. It's kind of wierd. It prints out 'za' and just before that a=1 and after( but before getting into the if condition where it changes its value) a= 1.6 million :( why that?
You can see in this picture : [link](http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagen-code-8128507.html)

Comment: @user1830562 I’m glad I was able to help. The bit of code in the screenshot is different from the code in your question above—I'd have to see all the code to be able to figure it out. In any case, since you're new to the site, please be sure to [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) any responses that are helpful, and [mark as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) the best answer to your question. If you don't regularly do this, people will be less likely to answer your questions in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again andrew! Well, is the same code but I changed "a" to a long long int instead of being just an int. Besides, there are three printf and two system pauses but just for checking the code and getting the image I posted! Sorry that I don't vote you up because I need 15 of reputation and I don't have them yet :(